# A huge data storage problem

Tags: database, database-design, sqlite, postgresql, data-structures

I'm starting to design a new application that will be used by about 50000 devices. Each device generates about 1440 registries a day, this means that will be stored over 72 million of registries per day. These registries keep coming every minute, and I must be able to query this data by a Java application (J2EE). So it need to be fast to write, fast to read and indexed to allow report generation.
Devices only insert data and the J2EE application will need to read then occasionally.
Now I'm looking to software alternatives to support this kind of operation.

- Putting this data on a single table would lead to a catastrophic condition, because I won't be able to use this data due to its amount of data stored over a year.
- I'm using Postgres, and database partitioning seems not to be a answer, since I'd need to partition tables by month, or may be more granular approach, days for example.

I was thinking on a solution using SQLite. Each device would have its own SQLite database, than the information would be granular enough for good maintenance and fast insertions and queries.

What do you think?

Comment: Too generic a question. Totally depends on the kind of data/queries etc.

Comment: So, to be more specific, the data are GPS coordinates that are inserted on the database. The queries would be reports like: "show me where the device 1234 was on the month of july 2010".

Comment: Did you already install PostGIS in your database?

Comment: I have PostGIS installed, why:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Record only changes of device positions - most of the time any device will not move - a car will be parked, a person will sit or sleep, a phone will be on unmoving person or charged etc. - this would make you an order of magnitude less data to store.
2. You'll be generating at most about 1TB a year (even when not implementing point 1), which is not a very big amount of data. This means about 30MB/s of data, which single SATA drive can handle.
3. Even a simple unpartitioned Postgres database on not too big hardware should manage to handle this. The only problem could be when you'll need to query or backup - this can be resolved by using a [Hot Standby](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hot-standby.html) mirror using [Streaming Replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION) - this is a new feature in soon to be released PostgreSQL 9.0. Just query against / backup a mirror - if it is busy it will temporarily and automatically queue changes, and catch up later.
4. When you really need to partition do it for example on device_id modulo 256 instead of time. This way you'd have writes spread out on every partition. If you partition on time just one partition will be very busy on any moment and others will be idle. [Postgres supports partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) this way very well. You can then also spread load to several storage devices using [tablespaces](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html), which are also well supported in Postgres.

Comment: Good suggestion on partitioning by device_ids. But over time the partition would be too big, don't you think?

Comment: Consistent hashing is better than device_id modulo 256. See http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/consistent-hashing/

Answer (score 2):

Time-interval partitioning is a very good solution, even if you have to roll your own.  Maintaining separate connections to 50,000 SQLite databases is much less practical than a single Postgres database, even for millions of inserts a day.

Depending on the kind of queries that you need to run against your dataset, you might consider partitioning your remote devices across several servers, and then query those servers to write aggregate data to a backend server.

The key to high-volume tables is: minimize the amount of data you write and the number of indexes that have to be updated; don't do UPDATEs or DELETEs, only INSERTS (and use partitioning for data that you will delete in the future—DROP TABLE is much faster than DELETE FROM TABLE!).

Table design and query optimization becomes very database-specific as you start to challenge the database engine.  Consider hiring a Postgres expert to at least consult on your design.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is time for a db that you can shard over many machines? Cassandra? Redis? Don't limit yourself to sql db's.

Answer (score 1):

Database partition management can be automated; time-based partitioning of the data is a standard way of dealihg with this type of problem, [and I'm not sure that I can see any reason](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html) why this can't be done with PostgreSQL.

You have approximately 72m rows per day - assuming a device ID, datestamp and two floats for coordinates you will have (say) 16-20 bytes per row plus some [minor page metadata overhead.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/storage-page-layout.html)  A back-of-fag-packet capacity plan suggests around 1-1.5GB of data per day, or 400-500GB per year, plus indexes if necessary.

If you can live with periodically refreshed data (i.e. not completely up to date) you could build a separate reporting table and periodically update this with an ETL process.  If this table is stored on separate physical disk volumes it can be queried without significantly affecting the performance of your transactional data.

A separate reporting database for historical data would also allow you to prune your operational table by dropping older partitions, which would probably help with application performance.  You could also index the reporting tables and create summary tables to optimise reporting performance.

If you need low latency data (i.e. reporting on up-to-date data), it may also be possible to build a view where the lead partitions are reported off the operational system and the historical data is reported from the data mart.  This would allow the bulk queries to take place on reporting tables optimised for this, while relatively small volumes of current data can be read directly from the operational system.

Most low-latency reporting systems use some variation of this approach - a leading partition can be updated by a real-time process (perhaps triggers) and contains relatively little data, so it can be queried quickly, but contains no baggage that slows down the update.  The rest of the historical data can be heavily indexed for reporting.  Partitioning by date means that the system will automatically start populating the next partition, and a periodic process can move, re-index or do whatever needs to be done for the historical data to optimise it for reporting.

**Note:** If your budget runs to PostgreSQL rather than Oracle, you will probably find that direct-attach storage is appreciably faster than a SAN unless you want to spend a lot of money on SAN hardware.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit of a vague question you are asking. And I think you are not facing a choice of database software, but an architectural problem.

Some considerations:

- How reliable are the devices, and how
  well are they connected to the
  querying software?
- How failsafe do
  you need the storage to be?
- How much extra processing power do the devices
  have to process your queries?

Basically, your idea of a spatial partitioning is a good idea. That does not exclude a temporal partition, if necessary. Whether you do that in postgres or sqlite depends on other factors, like the processing power and available libraries.

Another consideration would be whether your devices are reliable and powerful enough to handle your queries. Otherwise, you might want to work with a centralized cluster of databases instead, which you can still query in parallel.

Comment: The devices and J2EE are separated entities. The devices only write, and the J2EE app reads occasionally.
- The devices will be connect to the querying software through the database.
- The data must be failsafe, so losing data is no good.
- The devices will not query for data, they only generate the data.